# Python script ran by cron still use memory after finished

Tags: python, cron

I have a cron task that executes a python script and the process still exists after finished. If i let the cron execute for a week the computer memory used by multiple processes of that script is huge.

Currently i have another cron task that selects all the processes created by that script and kill them.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: if issue is with the script then probably you should share it

Comment: You're right, It was a issue with the code. I voted to close this thread.